# Dokuwiki sends Ajaxrequest to not existing file

Tags: php, dokuwiki

my dokuwikiinstallation at http://www.umingo.de makes some odd moves.

with each pageload, at the end the file /lib/exe/doku.php is called like 10 times 
[image: Google Developer Network view]

The odd thing:

there is no file /lib/exe/doku.php. i even downloaded a fresh dokuwiki installation. there is also no file in the exe folder.

how can i disable this useless ajax calls? i have investigated this behaviour 2 hours but have no clue how to fix it.

Comment: It's not being called 10 times, it's called only once, but the page always redirect to itself. If the file doesn't exist, I would look at the `.htaccess` to see where this redirection is coming from.

Comment: thx. i just created an empty dummy file and the calls are vanished. or at least it is just one.